# The "real" Newton's method?

Tags: soft-question, newton-raphson

I am an electrical engineer and don't have much background in numerical analysis. I am working on a problem which requires root-finding and many papers in the field refer to "Newton's method".

I found two "definitions" of this-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization

The first one uses the function and its first derivative while the second definition uses the first derivative and the second derivative during the iterations. So which of these are authors usually referring to when they talk about Newton's method?

Comment: These are the same: the "second one," as stated at the beginning of the article you link, is Newton's method applied to $f'$ (not to $f$) to find a critical point of $f$. (Because a critical point of $f$ is a root of $f'$)

Comment: Right. That makes sense. Thanks